# How to make left line of "lstlisting" block solid in the "acmart" document?

Tags: listings, acmart

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=leftline]
Hello,
world!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Is it possible to make the left line solid instead of dashed? It is solid, by the way, when the document class is `article` instead of `acmart`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that using `tcolorbox` for adding frames is better. Anyway, here's a patch that should work.

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=leftline]
Hello,
world!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]